# How can I add a new custom language

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.2.3. Now I have to add some more languages like Hindi (India), Bengali (Bangladesh), Tamil (India). Is there any extension for those language or do we have to add it manually and how could I add those languages manually?

Comment: You need to create different store view for different languages

Comment: You can read more [here](https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/) and [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to add new language, you need to create a new store view and set desired translation to this store view.

For more detail, follow these links:

https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/
http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-install-a-new-language.html

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

I got the hindhi language package from the above link, i added the package on the server, normally the site loads in english. when i changed the language to hindhi the site was loaded in english instead of hindhi

please check the below link: 
http://kaybs.in/magento/magento/

Comment: This package is working. Please check below screen-shot:
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/410642/2wc8hmlnebusb03f7l79

Comment: Login as customer in your website and Click on Address Book tab of My Account section.

You will see translated countries in drop-down.

Comment: This package is translating very few string that's why you are not able to identify. 
Download any other package like  `German (Germany)` language package and check.